# Install YoastSEO.js github repo using Git bash

Tags: node.js, github, npm, gruntjs, git-bash

I am trying to install Yoast.js using Git bash & Github but is stuck. I am installing Yoast.js from its [Github repository](https://github.com/Yoast/YoastSEO.js).

When I open up the example page located in `YoastSEO.js\examples\browserified\index.html` there is no styling or js included. Just a couple of textareas. My console shows a 404 error with `example-browserified.js` missing. What am I doing wrong? Below is the step I am running in order to install Yoast.JS:

```
cd <newsite folder>
git clone https://github.com/Yoast/YoastSEO.js
cd <YoastSEO.js folder>
npm install
npm install -g grunt-cli
grunt build
# Open index.html in the example folder as described above
```

Answer (score 1):

first configure webpack or laravel mix

then simply run ***npm install yoastseo --save***

Comment: Thank you @Mishuk Adhikari. I tried running the command you mention but ran into a error. Not really sure which files/folders I should rename: "npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "yoastseo" under a package also called "yoastseo". Did you name your project the same as the dependency you're installing?"